# Plotting lineArcs with turf.js that don't match up with their surrounding geodesic strings

Tags: google-maps, geospatial, gml, turfjs

#### Background

We are supplied with some AIXM data (an XML based superset of GML) which describes polygon areas on a map as a mix of GeodesicStrings (a list of coordinates) and ArcByCentrePoints (a centre point coordinate with a radius, start bearing and end bearing). We are taking this data and converting it into a simple list of coordinates that we then display using a Google maps polyline.

#### Problem

When we plot a shape with an arc, the start and end points of the arc *usually* don't match up with the end point of the preceding line and the start point of the subsequent line. It looks as if the radial distance is out by an amount which doesn't appear to be proportional to the radius. See screenshot: interestingly the smaller arc at the top seems fine but the larger arc is inset.

[image: Bad arc]

We're pretty sure the data is correct because it looks fine when we use a third party tool to visualise it, so we're doing something wrong.

#### Implementation

We are using the **turf.js** library to convert the arc description into a set of points using their [lineArc](http://turfjs.org/docs/#lineArc) function. Internally this utilises their [destination](http://turfjs.org/docs/#destination) function which *"uses the Haversine formula to account for global curvature"*. We combine these generated points, in the correct sequence, with the points taken directly from the preceding and subsequent GeodesicString elements to give us our final polygon.

#### Data

- Input: [Fragment of AIXM (GML) describing polygon](https://www.codepile.net/pile/3kxEWE87)
- Output: [Resulting list of points](https://www.codepile.net/pile/VN3P1xzM)

#### Help!

I'm aware this question is light on code but I hope I've described the problem adequately and that some kind person with more GIS knowledge than me (>0) might be able to point me in the right direction. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've given a couple of presentations on debugging and one of the things I say is that you should keep an open mind and shouldn't get too fixated on a possible cause of a bug because you can waste a lot of time tracking down a false lead.

Sadly in this case I didn't take my own advice. I was so obsessed with the idea that the problem arose from a complex cause, such as issues with the implementation of the Haversine formula, that I overlooked the far simpler answer. My code was taking a string representation of the radius, including the units (e.g. nautical miles or meters) and converting it into kilometres. Sadly I was using **parseInt** rather than **parseFloat** as part of this and so instantly losing precision. It was a simple as that - a schoolboy error.

Big thanks to Stefano Borghi, a maintainer of Turf JS, for all his help with this and for helping me see the wood for the trees.